# Adding links to a best-practices Q&A to all questions on a topic (C/C++ bitwise-rotate questions in this case)

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I'm posting here to make sure what I'm doing is ok.

I've been going through questions asking about bitwise rotation, and adding comments with a link to [a community-wiki question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c) with a community-wiki answer.

I kind of re-purposed that question, rather than the [newer question where I posted a more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387778/near-constant-time-rotate-that-does-not-violate-the-standards/31391611#31391611), partly because both the question and answer were community-wiki, so I felt justified in changing them.  My goal here is to increase the chance that people will copy-paste rotate code into their apps that compiles to a single instruction, rather than a branch or cmov like gcc makes for the code from Wikipedia.  If I was doing this for rep, I'd be linking directly to my answer, not the community-wiki answer.

The next-best option would have been to post a question and answer it myself, right?  Rather than change the code in the high-voted and accepted non-wiki answer on another question.

Trying to mark all the how-do-I-bitwise-rotate questions as duplicates of one best-practices answer seems unlikely to work.  It's unlikely that 4 more people will come along and mark it, too.

Questions I've touched so far:

- [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c).  (the community-wiki Q&A)  Editted question title.  Replaced contents of the accepted answer with a short version that doesn't ramble on too much, and a link to my longer answer.
- [Near constant time rotate that does not violate the standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387778/near-constant-time-rotate-that-does-not-violate-the-standards).  Where I originally left my long answer (which is unfortunately not the accepted answer on that Q).
- [How to perform rotate shift in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835469/how-to-perform-rotate-shift-in-c).  (edited link into the accepted answer, but didn't touch its code.  Also left my own answer, which I should prob. delete.  I did that before finding the community-wiki question which some other questions already had links to.)

---

- [Bitwise rotate left function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134805/bitwise-rotate-left-function) (edited link into the accepted answer, didn't touch code).
- [Rotate left in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942168/rotate-left-in-c-c)  left a comment
- [How does the x86 ROR instruction works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048190/how-does-the-x86-ror-instruction-works#comment52011858_10048190)  left a comment
- [Problem with Bitwise Barrel Shift Rotate left and right in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289316/problem-with-bitwise-barrel-shift-rotate-left-and-right-in-c-sharp#comment52011825_7289316) (yes, I did notice this was C#, not C/C++).
- [Rotate right by n only using bitwise operators in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895604/rotate-right-by-n-only-using-bitwise-operators-in-c#comment52011705_21895604) left a comment in case someone ends up at this weird hands-tied-behind-your-back question which wanted rotates without casting to unsigned.
- [Why don't we have bitwise rotate operators in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540659/why-dont-we-have-bitwise-rotate-operators-in-c-c#comment52011529_30540659) left a comment
- [Bitwise Rotate Right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176317/bitwise-rotate-right#comment52011327_27176317) left a comment
- [bitwise rotate operation for arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799460/bitwise-rotate-operation-for-arduino#comment52011250_16799460) left a comment

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're doing, but do you feel confident it will really deter the dupes ?

Comment: @Coffee: No, I don't think it will stop new dupes.  I'm just asking for some oversight while I go and add links to my answer all over the place in the existing dupes.  Like I said, the goal is make sure people that google on C rotate get to what I believe is the current best recommendation for coding it.  No undefined behaviour with any inputs, and a single rotate insn generated by current compiler versions found in stable-release OSes.  (gcc 4.9.2, clang 3.5).  (Older gcc/clang only see the rotate if the count is a compile-time constant.)

Comment: I also updated https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift#Implementing_circular_shifts

Comment: My gut feeling is that editing other peoples answers in this way might be problematic as you're sort of making the original authors voice your assertion (which might be correct) whether they share your point of view or not. Similarly changing the CW to start with "see my answer" makes it look like "my" refers to the original author. I can appreciate your intentions, but maybe there is a better way, for example flagging as duplicates and using meta to get 4 more people to support the dupe votes which shouldn't be hard if what you assert to be the best practice indeed is.

Comment: @jpw: I left comments in every case where there was a good visible place to leave one, for exactly the reason you gave: that stepping on other people's answers isn't ideal.  I'll think about the wording of the CW answer, too.  I wasn't totally happy with my phrasing either.

Comment: @jpw: I cleaned up the wiki to not say "my" anymore.  You're right, that was silly and self-aggrandizing or confusing.  Thanks again for the feedback.  Do you think it's worth the effort of getting people to help flag the actual duplicates?  I'm inclined not to bother, but for any fresh rotate questions that come along, I'll certainly flag them as dups of the best-practices Q&A while they're still fresh.

Comment: You can always solicit close vote requests in a chat room as opposed to hoping that someone else with > 3k rep will stumble onto the same question. I recently made a [UserScript](https://rawgit.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/master/SECloseVoteRequestGenerator.user.js) ([install / usage info](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts)) to generate a close vote request for the question you're viewing and send it to a chat room of your choosing.