# Does this edit change the meaning of the answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-edit

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/939206/3853934) has been recently [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/939206/revisions#spacer-f7f09381-4db0-4ec3-afe4-fe31a4adb204) (revision 4). This edit adds a lot of new information, which according to [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275180/3853934) is not a right thing to do. However, the author of that edit disagrees with that. Here are some messages they posted in chat:

> Completely changing the content of an answer is bad. Adding information to an answer is not necessarily bad, and it is up to the OP to roll it back if they feel it conflicts with their intent.
>
> In your example you added two more solutions to an existing answer. I did not add any solutions, I only added more examples using the same solution in a manner that is easier for other users to read, therefor increasing the usefulness and quality of the answer, which is the whole point of editing. So you could say that I was only improving the presentation of the content which was already in the answer.

<sub>See [this conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/conversation/conversation-between-gothdo-and-tiny-giant) for more context.</sub>

Is that edit appropriate, or should it be rolled back?

I think we've reached a consensus that edits shouldn't change the meaning of the post. Therefore, I want to ask more specifically: **does that edit change the meaning of the answer?**

Note that I don't want to judge the author of that edit. I'm not asking this question to prove they're wrong. I just want to know if editing posts like that is appropriate. In the Suggested Edits review queue I usually reject such edits as "attempt to reply" or "clearly conflicts with author's intent", but maybe I misunderstood something and I need to change my behavior.

Comment: Upvoting because this is  good question, not because of agreement/disagreement. This issue is one that the "don't change answers" seems to conflict with the original intent of being a (somewhat) collaboratively edited wiki-like resource.

Comment: You did the same thing as Tiny Giant here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40802071 you generalized the answer (and the question) and both you and Tiny Giant made good edits. Now I think the Q&A with more views is probably better as canonical duplicate instead of the newer one. Generalizing the question there wouldn't be a bad thing too the same as you did on the new one. (I also have to say seeing that you rolled back the edit from Tiny Giant, while generalizing the newer Q&A and then close voting the older one it seems a bit like you just want the newer one as canonical.)

Comment: @Rizier123 I hadn't noticed that. In some ways, these edits are even more radical than what Tiny Giant did, as the question was also changed. Furthermore, this question was posted less than 24 hours ago, which means there should be no difficulties in contacting the authors for to discuss the plans of generalising the question. I would say these edits are more clearly problematic than the one by Tiny Giant.

Comment: @Rizier123 IMO my edits only generalized the question and the answer, while Tiny Giant's edit added a new content.

Comment: I was always under the impression that that rule is actually ''Don't put words in the author's mouth that would affect the perception of their answer.'' So if you write ''foo means bar'' and I add ''bar means cux according to the dictionary'' that's a valid edit. Same as adding examples.

Comment: I encourage you to not accept an answer so quickly after it was posted. Would you mind letting the community vote before featuring the answer that the top of the list? Accepting such an answer before allowing the community to vote on it may show bias towards one side of the argument.

Comment: @TinyGiant I think the answer I accepted expresses best what I think about it. The community can still vote on it. The checkmark means only that it's the best answer for *me*—it doesn't necessarily mean that the community thinks the same way. Also, featuring it on the top will attract more votes anyway.

Comment: I think we need @Shog9 to post another apple/orange story, this time covering what a good/bad edit should be.

Comment: Recommended read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/213575 and another discussion worth reading too http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316817/792066

Comment: @g00glen00b oh but Shog did http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313762/792066, and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066

Comment: @Braiam not enough apples though :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In *this particular case*, there's the further issue that **the code added in the edit does not describe the same technique** as the original answer.  Thus, it *does* factually change the meaning of the answer, and should not have been made without the original answerer's consent.

---

To be more specific, the original code in bradhouse's answer defines a "callback factory" function that takes the `extraStuff` parameter(s) supplied by the caller, and returns an inner function that is suitable for use as a callback to the library function `$.json()`, and, being a closure, has access to both `extraStuff` as well as to the parameters passed to it by `$.json()`.

The "more basic example" [added in the edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/939206/revisions) by Tiny Giant, on the other hand, has the callback code take in both parameters directly, making it unsuitable for direct use as a callback parameter to the library function.  (In the simplified example, all that happens if you try is that one of the logged values is undefined, but in practice any attempt to do anything with the undefined parameter other than to log it would likely crash.)  Instead, to invoke the library function using that callback code, the caller needs to define a wrapper function that *does* take (only) the parameters provided by the library function, and invokes the actual callback with the extra parameters.

In effect, rewriting both examples to use the same syntax and variable / function names, the difference is between the original:

```js
function callbackFactory (extraStuff) {
    return function (callbackParameter) {
        // do something with extraStuff and callbackParameter
    };
}

function userCode (...) {
    libraryFunction(callbackFactory(extraStuff));
}
```

and the "simplified" method introduced in the edit:

```js
function customCallback (extraStuff, callbackParameter) {
    // do something with extraStuff and callbackParameter
}

function userCode (...) {
    var callbackWrapper = function (callbackParameter) {
        customCallback(extraStuff, callbackParameter);
    };
    libraryFunction(callbackWrapper);
}
```

Effectively, the latter method shuffles some of the complexity from the callback definition to the caller.  The relative merits of the two approaches can be argued, and generally depend on the surrounding context (e.g. whether the same callback is used from more than one place in the user code), but the important thing here is that *they are not the same.*  Thus, an edit that effectively adds one as a "simplified version" of the other is not only excessively presumptuous, but also factually incorrect.

Comment: I argue that it *is* the same while being the most simplified version of the same concept. The important concept here is not factory functions, it is the fact that function statements create new lexical environments, and lexical environments inherit variable definitions from their outer environment reference. Hence, it *is* the most simplified version of the same code, with as little code as possible, requiring the least amount of supplementary information to understand for future viewers.

Comment: I do understand your position though, and am grateful that you gave me the courtesy of explaining your position instead of just stating it. Up voting because of this, not because of agreement

Comment: @TinyGiant: I agree that both versions do use closures to capture variables from an outer scope (although it should be noted that, with appropriate argument ordering, the latter version could be trivially rewritten to use `.bind()` instead). However, that is where the similarities end, and I would say that, *as answers to the original question*, they are very different. In any case, if your goal was to turn this answer into a canonical explanation of how JS closures work, note that [we already have a pretty good canonical Q&A for that.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102)

Comment: "as answers to the original question, they are very different" I think we're going to have agree to disagree here, because I believe that the arguments in my previous comment negate this point. As far as making it a closure canonical, that would be simplifying it to the point of actually changing the meaning, as it would no longer be about callbacks, which is what I believe is bringing googlers to the question.

Comment: After reading my previous comment I realize that I may not have fully explained my point. While I don't believe that the differences between the two code blocks are relevant to the topic, I would be fine with your "correct" version in the edit.

Comment: Though i disagree with your assessment that my version being a simplified version of your version, which is a simplified version of the original, somehow exludes my version from being a simplification of the original. If anything, it may be an over-simplification of the original. But i dont believe that it is technically incorrect to say it is a simplified version of the original

Answer (score 24):

For context, that answer (and question) is from 2009 and viewed over 150K times.

So up until revision 3 this was the start of the answer:

> The solution is the binding of variables through closure.
>
> I haven't used the .post function in jQuery, but a quick scan of the documentation suggests the call back should be a *function pointer* accepting the following:
>
> ```
> function callBack(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {};
> ```
>
> Therefore I think the solution is as follows:
>
> ```
> var doSomething = function(extraStuff) {
>     return function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
>         // do something with extraStuff
>     };
> };
>
> var clicked = function() {
>     var extraStuff = {
>         myParam1: 'foo',
>         myParam2: 'bar'
>     }; // an object / whatever extra params you wish to pass.
>
>    $.post("someurl.php", someData, doSomething(extraStuff), "json");
> };
> ```

In revision 4 all that was added was a generalized basic example:

> As a more basic example, here is an example function that receives and calls a callback function, as well as an example callback function:
>
> ```
> function callbackReceiver(callback) {
>     callback("Hello World");
> }
>
> function callback(value1, value2) {
>     console.log(value1, value2);
> }
> ```
>
> This calls the callback and supplies a single argument. Now you want to supply an additional argument, so you wrap the callback in closure.
>
> ```
> callbackReceiver(callback);     // "Hello World", undefined
>  callbackReceiver(function(value) {
>     callback(value, "Foo Bar"); // "Hello World", "Foo Bar"
> });
> ```

I honestly don't see why that would be a bad edit, why it would be in conflict with the intent of the author or why it would be an attempt to reply to the author. That edit simply captures what the OP stated in their own words. The edit makes the answer better and wider applicable. [It doesn't change the meaning of the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11476/158100) and it [adds new relevant information missing from the post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11486/158100)

On top of that the editor left an extended comment, explaining their edit, so both the OP and any visitors would notice what has been done.

In our arsenal of moderation options editing is one of them. It seems like, based on the other answers, we're restricted to some grammar fixes, layout or rewording and I guess salvaging utter crap. That is a bit too restrictive, IMHO. I don't see why you couldn't and why we shouldn't edit a great answer into more greatness. That it is not your own post, who cares? Stuff gets better! Be happy!

All we have to do is judge the edit and the post on its merit. In this case I think it makes the post better and with that this small part of the internet.

Comment: This is bad because it changes the original meaning of the answerer's answer without their permission - which is specifically disallowed. The editor is not a coauthor. The editor can write their own answer or leave a comment requesting the improvement be added to the existing answer.

Comment: Yes @AaronHall and I wrote this answer because I disagree with the moderators position and already taken actions on this.

Comment: The edit lengthens the answer by a third by adding a parenthetical section that significantly changes the composition of the text. While we might argue whether that literally counts as "meaning", that is a substantial change to the answer which might be in conflict with the intent of a reasonable author.

Comment: @duplode it might be, yes. But it doesn't look like any of us so far found the definitive arguments to say it is in conflict.

Comment: @rene That being so, I believe the underlying question is how conservative we should be when a conflict is possible and plausible, but not certain.

Comment: @duplode Oh, I'm pretty sure users will be very conservative from this point onward ..

Comment: Yes, the editor is *definitely* a co-author, that's why their name appears in the edit history and below the post.

Comment: Recommended read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/213575

Comment: @duplode you might want to read Cody Gray's comment here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316817/overly-zealous-editing-of-answer-what-to-do/316832#comment309593_317033

Comment: @duplode I'm afraid that the way that your arguments are interpreted is: anything that isn't proofreading should not be done to answers.

Comment: Cody Gray's comment doesn't contradict the views that ground my comment above -- namely, that form and composition are also significant aspects of an answer, and that an edit shouldn't change a post more than what is needed to achieve the goals of the edit. In this specific case, my concerns don't imply Tiny Giant's edit should have been rolled back, as I have stated elsewhere in this discussion (e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338481/338488?noredirect=1#comment415461_338482 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338481/338488?noredirect=1#comment415660_338544
).

Comment: @Braiam "I'm afraid that the way that your arguments are interpreted is [...]" -- I can't control how people interpret my arguments. I can only try to influence that by posting further clarifications, as I am doing here. (By the way, I have rewritten my previous reply to you replacing "its goals" with "the goals of the edit", to further cut down possible sources of ambiguity.)

Answer (score 11):

I disagree with chrisF and Aaron Hall here and fully stand behind the editors (Tiny Giant) actions and think they were 100% correct and here is why.

### Situation

We have a canonical Q&A with over 150,000 views and 18 answers from 2009. The answer we are discussing about is the accept answer with the most upvotes. Currently the answer is specifically written to the question and is also outdated.

Now Tiny Giant edited the answer to generalize it with non-question specific code examples and also brought the answer up-to-date. He also adapted to the authors 'answering style' while editing, so the edit doesn't look out of place.

He still left the question-specific code in the answer and also added a comment under the answer informing the author about the edit and leaving it up to him to leave the edit or roll it back. While I think those two actions are optional they were perfectly correct.

Now when it comes to canonical Q&A's generalizing question and answer is an important part. It makes it a better choice as a duplicate since the answer isn't specifically written to one problem. Additionally it is simpler to understand and for the reader easier to adapt it to their own code.

Another smaller (optional) aspect of generalizing an answer is to bring all options, ways and solutions together into one answer, so that they are not all scattered and hidden away in various parts of many many answers.

**Do's and Don'ts**

I think generalizing canonical Q&A's is perfectly valid and welcome for the reasons mentioned above. If you generalize a Q&A, especially bigger ones, you have to be careful that you don't invalidate existing answers which are written specifically for the question by rewriting and generalizing the question. Invalidating answers is the last thing we want to do. Optionally, adapting to the authors 'posting style' (word choice, coding style, ...) while editing makes that the edit doesn't look out of place and reads as part of the answer.

If you add additional information to an answer you have to be a bit more careful. If you just add some side notes to the answer it is probably fine, but when you start to add more and more information with multiple examples and solutions you probably should post it as separate answer. But even then I think that there is also a certain line when there are too many answers on the question and all information is just scattered over all answers, so that it is better to put everything in the top answer instead of adding an additional redundant answer to the list.

I don't think Tiny Giant edited the answer so much that it should be a separate answer and even if he did I think in this example it would have been correct to edit that answer, since I think this specific Q&A exceeds the above mentioned line, so it would be more harmful to add another answer instead of editing the top answer.

Please also remember that we want to build a library with many useful Q&A's here on Stack Overflow for many users and not just for one. So Tiny Giant exactly did those two things here. He made the answer more useful and also understandable to more users.

### Solution

So what now?
Since this situation all got a bit entangled I think the best solution now would be to comment under the answer and ask the author to flag his own answer to be converted into a community wiki answer.

Probably neither of the two groups, the ones in favor for the edit nor the ones against it, will completely like that solution and that's why it's great. If the author will do that it will leave the answer up to the community.

---

<sub>From my own experience, since I already did such edits in the past, I can just say that many authors are very welcome to such edits and that you see a noticeable increase in views and votes after such edits.</sub>

Comment: I'm very much in favor of the solution you propose. Much more balanced that what was done already, by all parties involved.

Comment: Are you kidding? This question just 4 hours ago still contained "Thanks!", and even now contains a lot of completely irrelevant information. Please tell me, how is the line `var myDiv = $("#my-div");` relevant to the question? Calling it "canonical" is ridiculous. **Canonical question are supposed to be as simple as possible and as generic as possible.** This question isn't like that even in the slightest.

Comment: The fact that it has many views and upvotes is completely irrelevant in the matter of being a canonical question.

Comment: @Gothdo "Thanks!" and `var myDiv = $("#my-div");` of course are irrelevant and as I wrote in the comment under your question here it should be edited the same as you did on the other question from the newer Q&A. Tiny Giant tried to edit the answer into a generic canonical answer, which got then rolled back. So the Q&A could be easily edited into a good generic canonical. Now votes and views don't say if a Q&A is a canonical, but it is a factor to which Q&A you choose as canonical, so that is why I think it should be the canonical one and not the newer one.

Comment: *ask the author to flag his own answer to be converted into a community wiki answer*:  What?  How is that better than either rolling back to TinyGiant's first edit, or rewriting some of the new material, or replying to say "no thanks, I liked it without the updated example".  AFAIK, we haven't heard from the original author yet.  CWiki would give up all the rep that answer has accumulated, right?  If I was in his shoes, I wouldn't be interested in doing that, especially not as a first option (even though 300 upvotes is a bit inflated, I would prefer not to give up my lottery winnings :).

Comment: @Peter They would only lose future reputation, not past reputation gained from it.

Comment: @PeterCordes The author would just not gain any reputation from future votes. He would keep all current reputation and with CW the answer can be fully maintained by the entire community.

Comment: Ok, yeah then CW does make sense to hand off maintainership of the accepted answer to a canonical FAQ.  And is something that people might be willing to do.  Thanks for the clarification, @TinyGiant and Rizier.

Comment: Recommended read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/213575

Answer (score 10):

SO is a repository of useful answers / knowledge.  If you posted an answer years ago and haven't updated it yourself to generalize it once it gets a ton of traffic / upvotes, and aren't even around to review changes to it, SO as a community has a good reason to make edits to an answer that shows up in search results.

If the original author was around and did object, that would be their right and I'd have no problem with @bradhouse rolling back an edit.  Unless and until that happens, **current SO users can and should take responsibility for maintaining popular old answers.**  Careful well-thought-out edits that try to preserve the author's voice / intent / style are a Good Thing, and directly help make SO more useful to more people, and are worth a small to moderate intrusion into what the original author said.  Similar kinds of maintenance of old answers when they're out-of-date is officially encouraged; see [bluefeet♦'s 2015 question about how to encourage more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261817/how-do-we-encourage-edits-to-obsolete-out-of-date-answers).

Adding yet another answer instead of editing is not a viable alternative in cases like this. 
It doesn't really help solve the problem that an existing massively-upvoted-and-accepted answer is not as helpful as it could/should be for the many people who will read it in future.  There are already 18 answers, and a new one will be lost in the weeds for years, and still not shown first unless the still-active OP accepts it.  An edit is the only viable way to get better content for searchers in a reasonable time-frame.

---

Also, note that even though the edit added code, it didn't *change* any of the existing code.  Code edits are somewhat dangerous, but nobody is claiming that the code introduced by this edit is actually *wrong*.  So it has now been reviewed by many eyeballs without finding any problems, and thus should be fine to put in a highly-visible SO answer, because it looks like a much simpler example.

---

There are differing opinions on whether this edit would have been appropriate in some obscure answer with a couple upvotes on a low-traffic question.  I think it's fine on it's own merits, but [@Lightness Races in Orbit's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338481/does-this-edit-change-the-meaning-of-the-answer/338544#338544) does make a reasonable argument about "Not substantially the same as before the edit".  (This answer is a re-write of [my comments there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338481/does-this-edit-change-the-meaning-of-the-answer/338544?noredirect=1#comment415650_338544).)  That's debatable as a default criterion, and it's also debatable whether it's true or not for Tiny Giant's edit.  I have no problem accepting that as a valid position on edits in general, but that's not the point of this answer.

Everyone agrees that there is a limit.  The argument is that the specific circumstances of this edit change the limit from its "default" position, and should make it acceptable even to people who don't really like this kind of edit in general.

I'm not saying that old answers are a free-for-all.  Totally changing the answer, even if it's popular but wrong / dangerous / a bad idea, or just obsolete due to language changes, is still not ok even on ancient answers, especially where the author isn't around to review.  (Editing in a warning note may be appropriate, depending on how subtle + dangerous the problem is).

---

(If the user is still active, i.e. last seen within a couple days, I think it can be ok to make significant corrections and leave a comment.  If they're long gone, you have to take even more care as an editor to only change things when you're really confident you're correct and that you aren't introducing errors, as well as that you aren't distorting the answer so it's different from what the previous upvoters liked about it.)

Comment: Maybe the ["reasons to edit" guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) should be updated in light of this, if the community can agree on some way to phrase the "maintenance of popular old answers" reason. Or maybe link to this or other stuff on meta so when other editors are wondering the same thing, they can see the range of opinions from different users?  Keeping the help pages simple is good, but don't point to any way to resolve tricky / non-obvious cases.  I guess we don't want people making intrusive edits until they've been around enough to pick up what's appropriate?

Comment: This is one of the problems SE is trying to deal with http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/213575

Answer (score 8):

That edit was probably not appropriate. It adds a whole new example, even if it was "just" a more general answer, which would be more appropriate as a separate answer. While we do want answers to be improved, this usually refers to the spelling, grammar etc. of the text *accompanying* the code. If there's a technically better solution then that should be added as a new answer.

However, it was even less appropriate that the editor rolledback the rollback. If your edit has been deemed inappropriate the last thing you should do is reapply it. Take a step back and examine the edit and decide whether you went too far (or not far enough). Maybe you just need to redo part of the edit.

I've rolled it back again.

If the answer gets edited again I'll lock it.

Comment: What reasoning do you have for it not being appropriate? You simply posit that it is inappropriate.

Comment: @TinyGiant, I was just getting to that, but got distracted by the potential rollback war.

Comment: The rollbacks happened a while ago, no rollback war to be found. The OP here wants to close the question which owns the answer in question as a duplicate of a newer, more general question. I was trying to show that the original highly upvoted post could be improved to keep it's standing

Comment: It isn't "an more general answer", it is the same answer, with an example that doesn't contain all of the irrelevant noise. This should be up to the author of the post to decided whether or not to roll back

Comment: Again: **It should be up to the poster to decide whether or not to rollback the change**

Comment: @TinyGiant What if the poster is inactive? Should you be allowed to put words in their mouth in such cases?

Comment: I'm not putting words in their mouth, I'm using their own words to say the same thing in a way that is more generally applicable. jQuery has absolutely nothing to do with the actual solution, it is just meaningless baggage. The question is really asking how to supply additional information to a callback

Comment: Why does the state of the poster matters? If the edit adds value to a highly viewed post, why shouldn't we do that? The content matters, we don't care about users.

Comment: Yes indeed @Gothdo, what if the poster is inactive. Should highly voted posts continue to propagate half truths? At this point I would like to point out that content on SO also does not belong to the original poster, as said very clearly in our creative commons license and numerous other posts.

Comment: @Gothdo: *what if the poster is inactive*: If I'm considering making a borderline too-intrusive edit vs. posting my own answer, I always check whether the author of the answer is still active on SO (by looking at the last-active date on their profile).  If they're still active, I'll sometimes go as far as making edits that actually correct errors, since they can rewrite or just roll-back if they want.  (The usual reaction is a comment thanking me).  If they're not still active, I'll be much more conservative even if I know parts of the answer are wrong.

Comment: As an answerer, I wholly support ChrisF's position. If I had come across this edit in the wild, I would have reverted it. The can-dos and the don'ts for code are very narrow in scope, and the edit is far outside that scope. I have heavily scrutinized and continuously refined highly upvoted answers with *my* name on them. I don't want 2k rep users coming along and making me look bad with ill-advised new code or code changes - we don't have the QA in place to handle that, and I don't foresee it happening.

Answer (score 7):

I was the editor in question. Note that I have no stake in the outcome of this other than the fact that I truly believe that this edit is completely within the guidelines provided in the help center and throughout meta.

If there is an objective argument as to why this edit is inappropriate, I would happily read it.

---

> Does that edit change the meaning of the answer?

I posit that it does not change the meaning of the answer because the essential concept being conveyed is preserved in the new parenthetical section.

The core problem is highlighted in the title "pass more parameters into callback". The jQuery AJAX stuff was important to the OP, but it isn't what's bringing googlers to the question.

I felt that the specificity of the example was detracting from the answer's true potential usefulness, and was inclined to edit it to make it better.

What I was attempting to do with this edit was extract just that essential concept and display it in the shortest self-contained correct example I could muster, while still being easily understandable.

I also included a single line update about the new arrow function syntax (introduced in the 6th edition of the ECMA-262 standard released June 2015), and its added usefulness in this scenario.

I wanted to respect the author as much as possible, so I left the original code in place, generalized a basic explanation of the code, left the detailed explanation in the authors own words, and generally tried to be the least invasive as possible.

---

> You should have posted your own answer
>
> <sup>suggested by answerer's here</sup>

This was not a new solution, so posting my own answer would have just been duplication of effort and information. I'm reasonably certain that isn't Stack Overflow's goal.

As far as I can tell from the references I quoted here, there is nothing wrong with my edit, though I would happily read and consider any objective argument as to why my edit was inappropriate.

---

Quoting the help center editing privilege page: (emphasis original)

> #### When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks
>
> **Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.
>
> <sub>(https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)</sub>

Now to highlight the important parts of this:

> #### When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!

As I said above, I felt I could make the post better, and was inclined to do so. So far so good, but I'm not in the clear yet.

> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks

**To clarify the meaning of a post without changing it**

I attempted to clarify the "meaning", which I consider the essential concept that solved the core problem, by highlighting it in its most distilled form.

**Add addendums / updates as the post ages**

I added the one liner about the new arrow function statement syntax with a reference to relevant documentation.

---

Next, from [The Great Edit Wars (Stack Overflow blog 2009)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/): (emphasis original)

> So while the general advice on handling edit wars is roughly the same, here's some detailed guidance specific to our hybrid system.
>
> 1. As it says in the faq: **if you aren't comfortable with the community editing your posts, Stack Overflow may not be the right website for you.** What we do here is edit posts, together, to make them better and clearer. If you think that's crazy talk and we're all nuts, that's fine. Like I said: there are millions of existing traditional discussion forums on the internet. We're trying to do something different and perhaps more experimental here, so if you're not tolerant of that, posting here is probably .. not advisable. I don't like to see people go, but sometimes it's just not a good fit.
> 2. As it says on the sidebar of every edit page, here's what makes up **good editing practice** as we see it on Stack Overflow:
>
>    - Fix grammatical or spelling errors.
>    - Clarify meaning without changing it.
>    - Correct minor mistakes.
>    - Add related resources or links.
>    - Always respect the original author.
> 3. Editing is welcomed and encouraged. However, **if the author of the post is resistant to your editing changes**, even a perfectly legitimate edit based on the above rules, be the bigger man (or woman) and let them have it their way. Our goal here is not to cause friction between users, or to make everything perfect overnight. All we aim to do is gradually clean up and improve questions and answers together. When in doubt, just move on! There will be plenty of other posts and other edits you can make. In time, that reluctant author will learn how Stack Overflow works.

Again highlighting the important bits: (emphasis original)

> As it says in the faq: **if you aren't comfortable with the community editing your posts, Stack Overflow may not be the right website for you.** What we do here is edit posts, together, to make them better and clearer.

This emphasizes that community collaboration and editing are core concepts of Stack Overflow.

A post is not owned exclusively by the author. The author gets credit for coming up with the original revision and continues to profit over time for that, unless they decide to mark the post as community wiki.

When you mark something community wiki you are telling the world that you don't want any more credit for the content than the rest of the posts contributors.

When you don't mark a post as community wiki, you are not disallowing non-trivial edits.

> Editing is welcomed and encouraged. However, **if the author of the post is resistant to your editing changes**, even a perfectly legitimate edit based on the above rules, be the bigger man (or woman) and let them have it their way.

I left a comment after the edit informing the author and future readers of my edit and the reasoning behind it, while also encouraging the author to roll my edit back if they felt that it deviated to far from the original intent of their question.

> When in doubt, just move on!

I'm not in doubt, I am at this point reasonably sure that my edit was correct, and that the original roll back was in error.

I had attempted to discuss my position with the user who rolled back my edit, but did not receive a reply, so I re-applied my edit.

---

Finally, from [In Defense of Editing (Stack Overflow blog 2009)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/): (emphasis original)

> **Editing is the backbone of Stack Overflow**, and probably (along with the reputation system) one of the single most important distinctions between Stack Overflow and "just another forum".
>
> What's so special about editing? You might as well ask what's so special about editing on Wikipedia? Uh... everything?
>
> ...
>
> In The Great Edit Wars, we discussed some general guidelines for good editing. Please do read those. But I realized that I could have been clearer, and more specific. So here's some additional guidance.
>
> - **If you are going to edit a post, make sure you're substantively improving it.** Avoid making isolated, trivial edits, as they are the source of much friction. For example, don't bother changing "its" to "it's" unless you have several other edits to make in the same post. There has to be a legitimate case that your edit made multiple changes transforming the post from good to great -- or at least substantively improving it.

This details the fact that editing is one of the most important parts of Stack Overflow, and edits should strive to be substantial, and improve the post as much as possible, not be limited to simple grammar, spelling, and layout fixes.

Those things should be included *in* your edit at a minimum, but your edit should not consist solely of those things unless those things are the only thing that can be changed in a post.

Comment: Your solution is different than the solution of the OP. The OP solution is to create a new function which returns a function, and then call it and pass the result as an argument to `$.post`. Your solution, however, is to simply pass a wrapper function to the `callbackReceiver` function.

Comment: It's the same concept. We're arguing over the size of peanuts here.

Comment: Ridiculous to downvote this answer. I think tiny giant presents a very reasonable defense here..

Comment: @TheF No, it's not ridiculous. Downvotes on meta merely express disagreement. Personally, I agree that the edit should've been fine. Taking into account Tiny Giant already included a comment saying that it would be okay if the OP rolled it back, the decision to roll back should've been left to the OP. I voted accordingly on this answer. Others who disagree *should* downvote this answer, that's the whole point of voting here.

Comment: Not much to disagree with as it's quite an objective and reasonable! description of what happened and especially why the edit was rolled back.. whatever, too much 'brain' matter and too many characters that could've been used elsewhere on stack exchange 

Comment: While I still disagree with some of the arguments you raised elsewhere in this Q&A, this updated answer is a pretty reasonable defence of your edit. Accordingly, I have retracted my downvote.

Comment: I wonder about the possibility of moving the contents of your edit to the end of the answer. That way, your addenda would still be there, while disruption to the composition of the original answer would be minimised.

Comment: @duplode What I say always makes perfect sense, to me. Sometimes it takes me a bit to explain it in a way that makes sense to others. I would be open to moving the edit to the end.

Comment: As an answerer: You took community wiki style liberties with an answer with someone else's name on it. If I had come across it in the wild, I would have reverted it. As an answerer, my understanding of site policy only allows for limited editing of answers, especially ones with a large number of votes. I have a different position on [questions that are about to be deleted for problems](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7947/102438), but this violates and sets a bad precedence. (My apologies for my heavy-handed words earlier.)

Comment: @AaronHall: Community-wiki style liberties would be things like removing whole chunks of the answer and saying it a different way, or even saying something else if the original was wrong or outdated (an extreme case I've done: rev 3 of http://stackoverflow.com/posts/776523/revisions, which I [asked about on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302695/adding-links-to-a-best-practices-qa-to-all-questions-on-a-topic-c-c-bitwise) to see if I was doing the right thing).)

Comment: @AaronHall: I completely disagree with your assessment of how intrusive and meaning-changing the edit was.  As discussed in comments on your now-deleted answer to this meta question, it doesn't set a precedent because every edit still has to stand on its own merit.  Edits like this are not a new thing for SO.

Comment: We have a different standard for code, which he created out of thin air. The things you can do for code are very limited. The restrictions don't bother saying "Don't make new code" because that would be like saying, "5 is right out." To interpret that as "I can count to 5 because the instructions don't say I can't" is a willful misinterpretation. Now that's just my perspective, and I want to take a step back from this debate, because I've made some mistakes in tone that are undermining my position - and that's unfair to the community. I'm a new mod, please forgive.

Comment: @AaronHall: TinyGiant didn't even modify any of the OP's original code.  That's a huge and important difference.  The fact that the new code is just a more generic version of the original code makes it even less of an issue.  The original author of the answer hasn't been seen on SO for over a year, so unfortunately we may not have him weigh in on it, and does make it appropriate for moderators to take an interest, though.

Comment: A relevant chat discussion currently taking place between myself and Aaron as well as other users on this topic starts [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34285114#3428511). When this discussion has come to a conclusion, I will replace this comment with a link to a bookmark created at that time containing the entire discussion.

Comment: Recommended read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/213575

Answer (score 7):

The rules do not and cannot specifically address every combination of every scenario ever. The short text "changes author's intent" is a *summary* of a set of behaviours.

Was the answer resulting from the edit a bad answer? No.

Did the answer change the fundamentals of what the original author meant to say? No.

Was the answer after the edit substantially the same as the edit before the answer? Also, no, and therein lies the problem. Maybe you just don't want the rep from an answer of your own, but rep is a side-effect of our model, not the driving principle. This was no grammar correction or added clarifying paragraph: this was *a whole new answer*. And when you want to write a new answer, you should do just that.

I would have rolled back this edit.

Comment: It is not about not wanting the rep, it is about not duplicating content. Where does it say that the post has to be substantially the same after an edit? I think that flies in the face of the current policy which details that good edits make substantial changes. The paragraph was not a whole new answer. As I detailed in my answer, it is the exact same information already contained within the answer, presented in a manner that is easier to understand for more users, while keeping the original meaning of the post intact.

Comment: Do you have any objective arguments or references to relevant authoritative information to support your fourth statement? I have provided multitudes of such things in my answer justifying my position. You have taken a similar path to others who simply state that the edit is inherently bad, without providing any reasoning as to why it is.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I have no data and I don't claim to have any. I speak only from the heart as someone who, well, knows what he's talking about after all this time. If you are looking only for academic answers with statistics and affidavits, I encourage you to scroll up or down :) As for duplicating content, if that were a problem with answers, we would have a policy that multiple correct answers would be summarily merged or deleted. We don't, as I'm sure you've noticed at some point. As an aside, I'm baffled that any regular thinks this edit is appropriate. Have you been hiding under a rock?!

Comment: That's fine, but you're saying "This edit is bad" without detailing why it is bad, that isn't an argument, it's baseless statement of opinion. Community members should not be allowed to prevent other community members from improving content on the site because of their own personal opinion. If moderation action is going to be taken, it must be based on policy, not opinion.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I actually did explain my position. Take those four words out of my answer (if you can find them; I actually didn't use them but whatever) and you'll find 133 others to read and enjoy.

Comment: Being militant about your edit isn't really helping your case, either. What do you have to gain/lose here, exactly? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AAB858elJOw

Comment: I'm not being militant. I simply want a single objective reason why my edit is inappropriate. I have provided many for why it is perfectly within the guidelines set out for me. And is in fact encouraged by the help center documentation and all relevant information I can find on the topic.

Comment: +1 specifically for "The rules do not and cannot specifically address every combination of every scenario ever".

Comment: @duplode, yeah that's true, but I have detailed how my edit *does* fit within the guidelines.

Comment: This isn't a court of law, @Tiny, so if you're waiting for someone to spell out in A, B, Cs why you shouldn't do something, you'll be disappointed. Many people clearly feel that this was wrong, and frankly at a quarter past midnight on a Sunday evening I'm not inclined to go much beyond that to explain why I agree with them. The objective reason is what I already said it was: the answer before and the answer after are not the same answer. It's that simple. If you require a more scientific explanation you'll have to look elsewhere. But this is the reason almost everyone disagrees with you.

Comment: Then vote accordingly. Echoing a baseless statement without any semblance of an argument is not useful. Also, you have to be in a court of law to be able to expect a justification for corrective action taken against you now? I thought Stack Overflow was about being as objective as possible. You're willingly throwing objectivity into the wind and relying on baseless subjective statements and personal opinions to determine policy. I encourage you to [read this answer on the topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/4639281)

Comment: Okay I think we're done here.

Comment: @TinyGiant A complication is that not only the rules do not spell out what is to be done in this specific scenario, but also arguments for both sides can be found in them. If we reject both "all that the rules do not explicitly allow is forbidden" and "all that the rules do not explicitly forbid is allowed" as guidelines, that means we have nothing but precedents and interpretations to work with. In other words, perhaps there is no objective answer, and this whole discussion is an attempt to build (an approximation to) such an answer.

Comment: @duplode but my edit is justified by the guidelines. There is no reasoning supplied here that says the guidelines do not justify my edit. There is nothing saying why substantive edits are inappropriate despite being encouraged in documentation throughout the site. Just simply an implication that substantive edits are inappropriate. There is nothing saying how my edit alters the meaning of the answer. Only implications that it does change the meaning, and is therefore inappropriate. These are statements without justification.

Comment: @duplode At this time, an action taken by me is being moderated. I have done my very best to justify this action to the best of my ability, while no one has offered me the same courtesy of justifying why it is incorrect. I have been told the edit "is too large", "changed the meaning / substance of the post", "added lots of new information to the post", "is a whole new answer". I have addressed all of this with objective reasoning to the contrary, but no one has argued for any of those things other than to parot the original statement. There is no justification for the action taken.

Comment: @TinyGiant If we assume that "An edit shouldn't be too sweeping" is a principle, the claim to be justified is "The edit is too sweeping", and justifications for it were offered at various points. Paraphrasing: "It adds new material" (Aaron), "It is, in effect, a new answer" (Lightness), "It adds a whole new example" (Chris), "It changes the composition of the text quite a lot" (me). The discussion, then, becomes fundamentally about whether those are *good* justifications, and, if so, also about whether a rollback is the best resolution (e.g. it isn't as far as my objection is concerned).

Comment: @Duplode Those are not objective justifications, they are statements. If it was an objective justification, it would be measurable. Define: "too sweeping" and explain why that is a bad thing. Explain what new information is added that was not already contained in the answer, how that invalidates the edit. I have already explained how it is not a new answer repeatedly. "It adds a new example" even if I concede that yes it is a new code block, though the code contained in the code block already exists in the answer in a more specific form, what is wrong with adding a new example?

Comment: Saying that X is bad because it is Y, without explaining why Y is bad, does not justify the statement that X is bad. Likewise saying "In my opinion Y is bad" is not an acceptable justification.

Comment: This is the best answer that takes the "should-be-rejected" position.  It comes closer to convincing me than any of the others have.  However, I think doing maintenance on a highly-upvoted answer to a frequently-viewed question is useful, and still trumps this argument.  Perhaps there should be a pro-active review process for such special-case edits, like posting on meta with a proposed edit before making it?  Then experts in the tag can weigh in and decide that yes, this specific edit will be helpful to future readers, instead of having it only looked at after-the-fact. Thoughts, @TinyGiant?

Comment: @Peter the problem with that, as illustrated here, is the "experts in the tag" being on meta, reading the question and providing input, while also excluding anyone who is not an expert in the tag from contributing to the discussion. Of course, as here, what will happen is people who do not have sufficient knowledge on the topic to review the change will be commenting on how the change is inappropriate for subjective reasons, and as there will probably be more people who aren't experts than are commenting, it will be easier to derail with subjective arguments.

Comment: @Peter the only way I can see that working is if there was a new review queue, where you have to have objectively measurable qualifications in the given tag to review, being fed "substantial" edits to older posts with high views and / or high scores.

Comment: @TinyGiant: yeah, there's not really a good mechanism to solicit inputs from subject-experts, without bothering everyone in general.  SO could definitely use some kind of mechanism for reviews by tag-experts, e.g. for approving tag-wiki edits in popular tags.  Still, I suspect that much of the opposition here is based on the fact that you made an edit "the usual way", and that asking first would remove all the "slippery slope" and "too intrusive for a normal edit" objections.  Too bad there isn't a good place to propose such edits...

Comment: @Peter My problem is that no one has offered an argument as to how the edit is technically incorrect, or objectively inappropriate. All arguments against the edit to this point have been based on subjective criteria with little to no explanation of how the edit fits the subjective criteria. It would definitely be nice if there was a place where such edits could be proposed and reviewed by subject matter experts, I would be much less frustrated right now.

Comment: @TinyGiant: *Was the answer after the edit substantially the same as the edit before the answer? No* is a coherent reason.  I can see why some people might feel that edits need to satisfy that criterion.  I don't agree, but I think it's at least a valid position to take (unlike many of the other arguments).  And even for people that do take that position as a default, it's a rule that needs exceptions for cases like this, because it's not just someone's obscure answer, it seems to be a highly-visible part of SO's useful repository of knowledge / content.

Comment: @Peter Ok, but why is a post not being "substantially the same" (however you want to define that) after an edit as before the edit bad? How is "substantially the same" defined and measured in this context? Again X being Y doesn't make X a bad thing unless Y is a bad thing. If you cannot explain how Y is a bad thing, saying that X is bad because it is Y is not a valid argument.

Comment: @PeterCordes "it's a rule that needs exceptions for cases like this" -- This is an important issue relevant to this discussion that I forgot to mention in my previous comment. It does make sense to handle old, popular, highly-visible questions somewhat differently.

Comment: @duplode my point is that before you can discuss whether an argument is a good argument or not, it must be explained how the argument applies to the situation, and why that is a bad thing. Once that has been defined we can discuss whether that is a good argument or not. The first part of this is what has been missing so far.

Comment: @TinyGiant: *but why is a post not being "substantially the same" a bad thing*: I don't think this, but for the people that do, I'm guessing they think that "putting words in the author's mouth" is in general a bad thing, even though someone else's icon will show up in the "last edit" position at the bottom of the answer.  **Maybe \@LRO can expand on this**.  Maybe they don't see SO as a collaborative site, and that's where I disagree with them.  I just don't see a problem when the additions are highly related to what the post was originally saying, useful, and most importantly, correct.

Comment: @TinyGiant [1/2] General, broad-brush justifications for "An edit shouldn't be too sweeping": (1) Respect for authorship and for the individual voice of the author -- even though authorship isn't ownership, and in many cases the will of the author should give way to the demands of content curation, Stack Overflow does recognise and give visibility to authorship in various manners. (2) The existence of alternatives to radical edits that fit the system better, such as posting alternative answers or self-answered questions.

Comment: @TinyGiant [2/2] That being so, it is generally agreed that there is *some* limit past which an edit is too sweeping and should be rejected. The rules do not state precisely what that limit is (they just give several common kinds of edits as examples), and, as this discussion shows, there are various views about the matter. To pick an arbitrary example, when ChrisF says it is a problem that you have added an additional example, the implication is that, regardless of anything else, adding an example is enough to cross the line.

Comment: That would be a reasonable argument. If the application to this edit was explained. The examples limitation seems arbitrary, but if properly explained may be a reasonable argument. Not to say that I would necessarily agree with the either argument. I'm surprised by this meta question because I am used to seeing much better explained positions an divided topics, and so far there has been very little effort put into doing that against the edit in this case. Obviously the community is divided given the voting. @duplode

Comment: @Peter I would be very happy if lightness explained and expanded their argument.

Comment: @duplode: *The existence of alternatives*: **Adding yet another answer is not a viable alternative in this case.**  (actually it might be, since the OP of the original question is still active; last seen 3 hours ago.  So he could accept a new well-crafted canonical answer.)  But unless that happens, it doesn't really help solve the problem that an existing massively-upvoted-and-accepted answer is not as helpful as it could/should be for the many people who will read it in future.  The question has 18 answers; how many people are going to scroll down far enough to see a new one?

Comment: @duplode: The way I see it: SO is a repository of useful answers / knowledge.  If you posted an answer years ago and haven't updated it yourself to generalize it once it gets a ton of traffic / upvotes, and aren't even around to review changes to it, SO as a community has a good reason to make edits to an answer that shows up in search results.  If the original author *was* around and *did* object, that would be their right and I'd have no problem with \@bradhouse rolling back an edit.  Without that, current SO users can and should take responsibility for maintaining popular old answers.

Comment: @PeterCordes On adding another answer: I agree with your assessment, and it weighs in favour of the edit. I only mentioned those two reasons in that comment in support of the very general principle that there should be a limit to the extent of edits. Exactly what the limit is, whether there should be exceptions, and where this specific edit stands in relation to it are separate (if related) questions.

Comment: Just to clarify and avoid misunderstanding: I'm not saying that old answers are a free-for-all.  Totally changing the answer, even if it's popular but wrong / dangerous / a bad idea, or just obsolete due to language changes, is still not ok even on ancient answers, especially where the author isn't around to review.

Comment: @duplode: The criteria for deciding where the limit is seems to be the crux of the matter.  I think everyone agrees there is a limit; we aren't arguing about that.  I'm making an argument that the specific circumstances of *this* edit change the limit from its "default" position.  Honestly, I think this was just plain a good edit, even without all of those circumstances, but I not everyone agrees with that.  But I hope I can get more people to agree that *this* edit was ok in *this* case, because of these reasons, even if they don't really like this kind of edit in general.

Comment: @PeterCordes I believe that the long-term maintenance argument in your "The way I see it..." comment is the strongest here in support of this specific edit, and that it is enough to justify it. (As I mentioned under Tiny Giant's answer, I would rather have the additions at the end of the answer than in the middle of it; that, however, is a secondary issue which is easy enough to solve.)

Comment: @duplode: Maybe the ["reasons to edit" guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) should be updated in light of this, if the community can agree on some way to phrase the "maintenance of popular old answers" reason.  Or maybe link to this or other stuff on meta so when other editors are wondering the same thing, they can see the range of opinions from different users.

Comment: @duplode: Thanks for the feedback that my argument made sense.  [I turned them into an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338481/does-this-edit-change-the-meaning-of-the-answer/338557#338557)

Comment: Recommended read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/213575

Comment: @lightness please see ilmari's answer here for an example of an explained position, as you seem to not understand what I mean by backing up your statements with objective arguments.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I addressed this complaint 18 hours ago, now you're back to the repeated personal insults? **Stop.**

Comment: @Lightness that was not intended as a personal insult. I made an observation that you do not understand what I mean by backing up a statement with objective arguments. Now that an answer has been posted whose position is against the edit and also contains objective arguments to back up its statements, it would be a good example of what I mean, so we could clear up any confusion about the meaning of my previous comments. I'm sorry that constructive criticism offends you.

Comment: @TinyGiant: It's not "an observation". Again. **STOP.** I "understand" perfectly; you will go further if you do not accuse those who disagree with you of only disagreeing because they "don't understand". In fact I agreed that I was not providing an objective argument, and I told you that I had no intention of doing so. Further comments from you will generate moderator flags, because I'm sick of it.

Comment: Re: your comment edit: I'm not accusing you of disagreeing because you don't understand. I'm simply stating that it seems that you misunderstand what I meant when I asked for an objective argument to back up your statement. You accused me of wanting this to be a court of law, and wanting academic answers with statistics and affidavits. To alleviate this misunderstanding I attempted to point you at an example of what I meant. I do not think that attempting to alleviate the misunderstanding and elevate the quality of answers here should be considered a personal insult.